# How to extract specific fields from a list in Python

Tags: python

Here is an example of 1 line form a large List, I save 200,000 such lines into a file one after the other for easier readability.

```
['{activities:[{activity:121,dbCount:234,totalHits:4,query:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,searchedFrom:PersistentLink,searchType:And,logTime:1469765823000},{activity:115,format:HTML,searchTerm:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,mode:View,type:Abstract,shortDbName:cmedm,pubType:Journal', 'Article,isxn:15506606,an:23776179,title:Journal', 'Of', 'Immunology', '(Baltimore,', 'Md.:', '1950),articleTitle:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite', 'antigens', 'as', 'targets', 'of', 'protective', 'human', 'immunity', 'to', 'Plasmodium', 'falciparum', 'malaria', 'for', 'vaccine', 'and', 'biomarker', 'development.,logTime:1469765828000}],session:-2147364846,customerId:s2775460,groupId:main,profileId:eds}']
```

From this line as above, I want to be able to extract 4 fields; namely- "query", "an", "shortDbName" and "profileId"

Any idea form anyone will be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Format your code so we can understand it please.

Comment: Your use of `'` seems questionable - is this `['{activities:[{activity:121,dbCount:234,totalHits:4,query:Identification',` meant to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

Your line looks very weird. However, assuming you store the line in a single string variable called 'mystring' you could do something like the following to parse out the value of query:

```
 query = mystring[mystring.find("query:"):mystring.find("searchedFrom:")]
```

this would produce:

```
query:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,
```

Comment: using variable names such as `str`, `list`, `set`, `id` bad practice, because it's reserved words for built-in types/functions

Comment: Ah yes this is true, my bad

Answer (score 0):

So, I made couple of changes and used your code like here to get the desired field query in response, but what if I want all 4 fields altogether at once ?

```
mystring = ['{activities:[{activity:121,dbCount:234,totalHits:4,query:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,searchedFrom:PersistentLink,searchType:And,logTime:1469765823000},{activity:115,format:HTML,searchTerm:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,mode:View,type:Abstract,shortDbName:cmedm,pubType:Journal', 'Article,isxn:15506606,an:23776179,title:Journal', 'Of', 'Immunology', '(Baltimore,', 'Md.:', '1950),articleTitle:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite', 'antigens', 'as', 'targets', 'of', 'protective', 'human', 'immunity', 'to', 'Plasmodium', 'falciparum', 'malaria', 'for', 'vaccine', 'and', 'biomarker', 'development.,logTime:1469765828000}],session:-2147364846,customerId:s2775460,groupId:main,profileId:eds}']
sanitizedmystring = str(mystring).replace('"', '')
print sanitizedmystring
query = sanitizedmystring[sanitizedmystring.find('query:'):sanitizedmystring.find('searchedFrom:')]
print query
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a the following **regex** -> `(query|an|dbCount|shortDbName|profileId):([A-Za-z0-9]*)` we should be able to capture the **key/value**
 pair from these fields. This should match any of those key words you mentioned followed by a `:` (*doesn't capture*) and any string following the colon that contains lower/uppercase/digit character(s). We then append all of the found results per tag to a dictionary (`key : [list of tags found]`).

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

def extract_fields(l):
    queries = []
    d = defaultdict(list)
    regex = r"(query|an|dbCount|shortDbName|profileId):([A-Za-z0-9]+)"

    for line in l:
        query = re.findall(regex, line) 
        for match in query:
            queries.append(match)
    for item in queries:
        d[item[0]].append(item[1])

    return d
```

**Sample output:**

```
l=['{activities:[{activity:121,dbCount:234,totalHits:4,query:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,searchedFrom:PersistentLink,searchType:And,logTime:1469765823000},{activity:115,format:HTML,searchTerm:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite,mode:View,type:Abstract,shortDbName:cmedm,pubType:Journal', 'Article,isxn:15506606,an:23776179,title:Journal', 'Of', 'Immunology', '(Baltimore,', 'Md.:', '1950),articleTitle:Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite', 'antigens', 'as', 'targets', 'of', 'protective', 'human', 'immunity', 'to', 'Plasmodium', 'falciparum', 'malaria', 'for', 'vaccine', 'and', 'biomarker', 'development.,logTime:1469765828000}],session:-2147364846,customerId:s2775460,groupId:main,profileId:eds}']

print extract_fields(l)
>>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'query': ['Identification'], 
'shortDbName': ['cmedm'], 'dbCount': ['234'], 'profileId': ['eds'], 'an': 
['23776179']})
```

Comment: This works but it terminates the 'query' after first " ' " following Identification and results in  ['Identification'], whereas the actual query field should extract ['Identification', 'and', 'prioritization', 'of', 'merozoite']